# Get element with a certain value, make it selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form with this disabled select element (I have disabled it with jquery)

```
<select class="select form-control" id="ifacility" name="facility">
    <option value="" selected="selected">------</option>
    <option value="1">Room 1</option>
    <option value="2">Room 1</option>
    <option value="3">Room 2</option>
    <option value="4">Room 3</option>
</select>
```

I want to use `Jquery` to find an option with a name eg `Room 2` and make it selected.

```
$(document).on('click', '.select-option', function() {
    var room = $(this).attr('value') //This is what gives the 'Room 2'
    //I want to select this room from the options and make it selected
});
```

Comment: Does the value change or Room 2 will always have the value 3?

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon no, its data from backend. Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't really need jQuery for this, so here's a plain-old JavaScript solution.

Declare this function:

```
function setOptionByValue(select, value){
    var options = select.options;
    for(var i = 0, len = options.length; i < len; i++){
        if(options[i].textContent === value){
            select.selectedIndex = i;
            return true; //Return so it breaks the loop and also lets you know if the function found an option by that value
        }
    }
    return false; //Just to let you know it didn't find any option with that value.
}
```

Use it like this:

```
setOptionByValue(document.getElementById('ifacility'), 'Room 2');
```

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/turer/1/edit)

Comment: He asked for jquery, and then you provided over-bloated javascript.

Comment: "over-bloated javascript" do you even understand how wrong this statement is?

Comment: "over-bloated javascript" = jQuery

Comment: @eg_dac the answer provided is magnitudes smaller and likely more efficient that using what jQuery does. It might not be what the OP uses at the end of the day but it is helpful, correct, and might teach the OP something else (not to mention anyone else who stumbles here).

Comment: he's already using jquery... so then how is 3 lines less efficient than 11. I do really like how you guys can't think past one word hahaha. you actually forgot that he already used jquery anyway.

Comment: @eg_dac That might be true, but I don't think that makes my answer *bad*. It still does what he wants, and it shows him the logic behind it. If he'd said, "I know how to do this in JavaScript, but how would you do it with jQuery?" then my answer would have been invalid, yeah.

Comment: think of this. if i were a client, and said use jquery, then the developer didn't use what was asked, he'd have no job. I have seen a lot of down votes for people not actually listening to the specifics of the question.

Comment: If i was the developer and you'd be the client. I wouldn't off taken the job :P

Comment: anyway, now people are just going in a path that is irrelevant. take it easy.

Comment: Hi @SomeGuy Am trying to fit this in my jquery since I wanted it to happen when a user clicks a link. Let me update the qn and see If you can help me fit it.

Comment: Alright guy, mediator here! Both jQuery and Vanilla solutions are good. jQuery has less lines but Vanilla is faster, end of story. Here's how to implement both method efficiently (used a prototype for vanilla) : http://jsfiddle.net/e8X4v/

Answer (score 3):

A jQuery solution using [filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/):

```
var room2 = $('#ifacility option').filter(function() { 
    return $(this).text() == 'Room 2';
});

// room2.val() = '3'
$('#ifacility').val(room2.val());
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jPxY5/1/)

Answer (score -1):

If you want to user jQuery to accomplish task, try this

```
$('#ifacility').find('option:contains("Room 2")').prop('selected', true);
```

It finds option by text and sets its selected attribute.

Comment: I've never heard on `[text=something]`. `[]` = attribute selector.

Comment: text is not an attribute, so can't be used as an [attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)